# IList<T> return as a generic

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, generics

I'm a beginner for coding ,and I was trying to create a search engine , but there s a part I dont know how to solve it that returns an IList as a generic,

```
public IList<T> Search<T>(string textSearch)
{

    IList<T> list = new List<T>();

    var result = new DataTable();
    using (Analyzer analyzer = new PanGuAnalyzer())
    {
        var queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "FullText", analyzer);

        queryParser.AllowLeadingWildcard = true;

        var query = queryParser.Parse(textSearch);

        var collector = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(1000, true);

        Searcher.Search(query, collector);

        var matches = collector.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;


        result.Columns.Add("Title");
        result.Columns.Add("Starring");
        result.Columns.Add("ID");

        foreach (var item in matches)
        {
            var id = item.Doc;
            var doc = Searcher.Doc(id);

            var row = result.NewRow();

            row["Title"] = doc.GetField("Title").StringValue;
            row["Starring"] = doc.GetField("Starring").StringValue;

            row["ID"] = doc.GetField("ID").StringValue;

            result.Rows.Add(row);

        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

but in this code , I couldn't return result ,it says Cannot Implicitly convert type 'Data.DataTable' to 'Generic.IList',An explicit conversion exists.so how can I solve this?

Comment: The prototype of your function indicates that it should return an `IList`, but you return a `DataTable` instead...

Comment: If you want to return the records in your DataTable you can use `return result.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList();`

Comment: Rather that return a `DataTable` why not just return a list of films (for example), eg `IList<Film>`

Comment: @Misery
Its still not working .
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.DataRow>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>'.

Comment: @Sean
I was using dataTable to get all of the data from database , so it s returns a Datatable like this
        DataTable Sample
         {
            get
             {
                var query =
                    from video in db.Video_List
                    select video;
                return ToDataTable(query.ToList());

            }
        }

        DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
            return dataTable;
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you don't want to support generics since it doesn't make sense and is impossible. You have a class, for example `Film`, then return a `List<Film>`, you don't need the `DataTable`:

```
public IList<Film> SearchFilms(string textSearch)
{
    IList<Film> list = new List<Film>();
    using (Analyzer analyzer = new PanGuAnalyzer())
    {
        var queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "FullText", analyzer);
        queryParser.AllowLeadingWildcard = true;
        var query = queryParser.Parse(textSearch);
        var collector = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(1000, true);

        Searcher.Search(query, collector);
        var matches = collector.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;

        foreach (var item in matches)
        {
            var film = new Film();

            var id = item.Doc;
            var doc = Searcher.Doc(id);

            film.Title = doc.GetField("Title").StringValue;
            film.Starring = doc.GetField("Starring").StringValue;
            film.ID = doc.GetField("ID").StringValue;

            list.Add(film);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Its little complicated...,actually I have a database  , and I used datatable to get the data like this:

             DataTable Sample
        {
            get
            {
                var query =
                    from video in db.Video_List
                    select video;

                return ToDataTable(query.ToList());



            }
        }

Comment: Its little complicated...,actually I have a database , and I used datatable to get the data like this: 

                        DataTable Sample { get { var query = from video in db.Video_List select video; return ToDataTable(query.ToList()); } } –

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement should be

```
result.AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

Don't forget to add namespace

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: I was trying to use this , and still got an error says, Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.DataRow>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>'

Comment: I was trying to use this , and still got an error says, Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.DataRow>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>' @Imad

Comment: Thanks for that, but actually, my purpose is by typing words to search data from datatable , so as you see above the code ,I need to define a 'string textSearch' to type the words and get the results not only get the list of the table  . So how can I solve that ?

Comment: @I didn't get you. Can you please elaborate what you want to achieve and what output you are getting?

Comment: So... I wanna build a search engine by using lucene.net and run it in API ,First i got a database ,and I was using datatable to get data  
    DataTable Sample
        {
            get
            {
                var query =
                    from video in db.Video_List
                    select video;

                return ToDataTable(query.ToList());



            }
        }

Comment: Then I created a Index class , cause , When I run it , It ll create a search index by using lucene.net
Lucene.Net.Store.Directory createIndex(DataTable table) {
            var indexPath 
            var directory 
            using (Analyzer analyzer {
              StandardAnalyzer)
               using (var writer ){
                     foreach (DataRow row in Sample.Rows)
      return (directory);
and it return an index for search (sorry for short code, words limited)

Comment: And what I showed the code in my questions is the third part, as you can see , the IList 'Search' ll collect and returns the results after when I typing something like "http://localhost:50624/api/SearchManager/obtain?key=aaa" and this 'key' ll be the string of textSearch in IList Search, and It ll gives all of results which contains aaa.

Comment: and my controller is like this :
    [HttpGet]
        public IList<Video_List> Obtain(string key)
        {
            return SearchEngineManager.Current.Search<Video_List>(key).ToList();
        }